# Duas classes ou mais em um mesmo elemento no HTML

Tags: html

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível atribuir duas ou mais classes no elemento do HTML. Por exemplo, eu tenho uma `div`, eu conseguiria atribuir duas `class` a ela?

```
<div class="primeira_classe" class="segunda_classe"></div>
```

Ou isso seria contra as regras do HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode ter dois atributos `class` na *tag*, mas pode ter quantas classes quiser, e isso é bem comum:

```
<div class="primeira_classe segunda_classe"></div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/MultiClass.html).

Comment: Então para eu colocar duas classes é apenas fazer um espaço entre elas tudo no mesmo atributo? Para manipular elas no CSS também é normal ou muda alguma coisa?

Comment: Sim, conforme está na resposta, e CSS você manipula cada classe, CSS não é HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [especificação do WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2), um atributo não pode aparecer mais de uma vez no mesmo elemento:

> *There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.*

Ou seja, se tiver algo como `<div class="abc" class="def">`, isso é inválido porque tem mais de um atributo com o mesmo nome (no caso, dois atributos `class`).

<sup>Lembrando que a comparação, conforme o texto acima, [é *case insensitive*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute), portanto mesmo se tiver `<div cLASs="primeira_classe" class="segunda_classe">`, ainda sim é inválido, pois `cLASs` e `class` são considerados o mesmo atributo - veja no [link já indicado](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute): "*All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically*").</sup>

Na prática, os *browsers* costumam ignorar da segunda ocorrência em diante (*os browsers costumam ser bem permissivos com HTML inválido*). Ou seja, usando o seu exemplo, somente a primeira classe seria aplicada:

```css
.primeira_classe {
    background-color: red;
}

.segunda_classe {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="primeira_classe" class="segunda_classe">
Fundo vermelho, mas letra não fica amarela (a segunda classe não é aplicada)
</div>
```

---

No caso específico do atributo `class`, [a MDN diz o seguinte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class):

> *The class global attribute is a **space-separated list** of the case-sensitive classes of the element*

Destaque para o trecho em negrito acima: o valor do atributo `class` é uma **lista** dos nomes das classes de um elemento, **separados por espaços**.

Sendo assim, para que o elemento tenha as duas classes, basta separá-las por espaço:

```css
.primeira_classe {
    background-color: red;
}

.segunda_classe {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="primeira_classe segunda_classe">
Fundo vermelho, letra amarela
</div>
```

---

Lembrando que esta restrição de um atributo só poder aparecer uma vez em um elemento vale para qualquer atributo (não somente `class`), em qualquer elemento (em qualquer *tag*).

Vale lembrar também que cada atributo tem suas próprias regras quanto a poder ter ou não múltiplos valores. No caso do `class`, basta separá-los por espaço, mas no caso de outros atributos, veja a especificação de cada um para saber se/como é possível fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Completamente normal, utilizado principalmente quando se tem uma classe do bootstrap por exemplo.

```
<div class="container-fluid primeira_classe segunda_classe"></div>
```